# setInterval() still being called after clearInterval()

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, clearinterval

I have my setInterval function called on click, but after I clear it using an End Timer button it continues to run. It's a countdown clock so I want to make 2 buttons, a reset button and and end button. Both will pretty much do the same thing except end will make both minute and second values 0 and reset will make minute 25. I'm new to javascript so I assumed clearInterval() would terminate the setInterval() function and not allow it to be called until the corresponding button is clicked again.

```
var minCount = 25;          
var count = 60;

$("#begin").click(function timer(){
    var count = 60;
    minCount = minCount - 1;

    var counter = setInterval(function(){
        document.getElementById("min").innerHTML = minCount;
        count -= 1;
        document.getElementById("sec").innerHTML = count;

        if(count < 10){
            document.getElementById("sec").innerHTML = "0"+count;
            if(count == 0){
                clearInterval(counter);
                document.getElementById("min").innerHTML = minCount;
                document.getElementById("sec").innerHTML = count+"0";

                timer();
            }
        }
    },1000)
});

$("#end").click(function(){
    clearInterval(timer);
    document.getElementById("min").innerHTML = "00";
    document.getElementById("sec").innerHTML = "00";        
});
```

Comment: `clearInterval(timer)`, timer???

Answer (score 1):

Why do you call `clearInterval(timer)` ?

You need to pass the `counter` interval.

However, you are defining it on the "begin click" scope, and calling it on the "end click" scope wouldn 't work. Try extracting it to a common scope (say, after minCount and count) and use that on `clearInterval`.

[Check this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q3jhjpfh/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the interval into a variable.
See example below:

```js
var minCount = 25;
var count = 60;
var counter;


$("#begin").click(function timer() {
    var count = 60;
    minCount = minCount - 1;

    counter = setInterval(function () {
        document.getElementById("min").innerHTML = minCount;
        count -= 1;
        document.getElementById("sec").innerHTML = count;

        if (count < 10) {
            document.getElementById("sec").innerHTML = "0" + count;
            if (count == 0) {
                clearInterval(counter);
                document.getElementById("min").innerHTML = minCount;
                document.getElementById("sec").innerHTML = count + "0";

                timer();
            }
        }

    }, 1000)
});


$("#end").click(function () {
    clearInterval(counter);
    document.getElementById("min").innerHTML = "00";
    document.getElementById("sec").innerHTML = "00";

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="begin">Begin</button>
<button id="end">End</button>
<div id="min">0</div>
<div id="sec">0</div>
```